# How to update Observable with value from a different Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having trouble to figure out how I can update the result of one Observable with the result of another:

```
this._http.get<JSON>(url, { params })
.pipe(map((res: JSON) => this.getObjectFromJson(res)))
.subscribe(myObject => {
    this.getValueToUpdate(myObject).subscribe(newValue => {
        myObject.some.value = newValue;
    });
});
// return Observable<myObect>;
```

What is the proper sequence of rxjs operators to achieve this without these `subscribe`s and being able to return the resulting Observable to be used later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap):

```js
this._http.get<JSON>(url, { params }).pipe(
  map((res: JSON) => this.getObjectFromJson(res)),
  switchMap(myObject => {
    return this.getValueToUpdate(myObject).pipe(
      // probably here you need also a catchError(err => ...),
      map(newValue => {
        myObject.some.value = newValue;
        return myObject;
      })
    );
  })
).subscribe(myObject => {
  // here myObject is updated with newValue
});
```

It allows to invoke another async operation and *switch* (i.e. observe) on that.
The inner `pipe`, using the `map` operator, allows to combine the result of the nested async operation with the previous result.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed!